# How to return a Future http function as boolean so that it can be used for furthur activity flow based on result of http response

Tags: json, http, flutter

This is a code for an edit user information http post, the response message will return if the edit is success or not. I want this function to be able to return a boolean so that the user interface class will be able to know if that post is success or not. In this following code, it returns Future which is unable to be put in if(bool) function. This EditCustomerPost class is called by the user interface class.

Is there anyway to return the result of this http post back to the user interface class (widgets class)? I want to return the result as 'bool success'.
Thank you for your help!

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './loginPost.dart';
import './loginPage.dart';
import './userInfoPage2.dart';

class EditCustomerPost {
  String jsonString;
  String reMsg;
  Map<String, dynamic> reMsgMap;
  bool success = false;
  BuildContext context;
  String token;
  String editWhat;

  EditCustomerPost({
    this.jsonString,
    this.reMsg,
    this.reMsgMap,
    this.context,
    this.token,
  });

  void showDialog1(String msg, bool success) {
    // flutter defined function
    String title = "Completed";
    if (!success) {
      title = 'Error';
    }
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text(title),
          content: new Text(msg),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void showDialog2() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Access time expired"),
          content: new Text("Please Login again"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // testcodepostrequest
  Future<bool> makePostEditRequest(String editWhat) async {
    // set up POST request arguments
    String url;
    if (editWhat == 'name') {
      url = 'http://firstcarestartup.appspot.com/customer/editName';
    } else if (editWhat == 'email') {
      url = 'http://firstcarestartup.appspot.com/customer/editEmail';
    } else if (editWhat == 'phoneNum') {
      url = 'http://firstcarestartup.appspot.com/customer/editPhoneNum';
    } else if (editWhat == 'profilePicture'){
      url = 'http://firstcarestartup.appspot.com/customer/editProfilePicture';
    }

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    };
    print('==========HTTP POST FOR EDIT PROFILE==========\n');
    print('json post edit header= ' + headers.toString());
    print('json post edit request= ' + jsonString);
    print('json string length: '+jsonString.length.toString());
    print('url: '+url);
    // make POST request
    http.Response response =
        await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: jsonString);
    // check the status code for the result
    // int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    // this API passes back the id of the new item added to the body

    reMsgMap = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (reMsgMap["error"] != null) {
      reMsg = reMsgMap["error"];
      success = false;
      if (reMsg == "jwt expired") {
        showDialog2();
      } else {
        print("error: " + reMsg);
      }
    } else if (reMsgMap["msg"] != null) {
      reMsg = reMsgMap["msg"];
      success = true;

      print(reMsgMap.toString());
    }
    if (success) {
      showDialog1(reMsg, success);
    }
    return success;
  }
}
```

Comment: There's something odd with your code. Your class is not extending a Stateful or Stateless Widget. Apart from that, why can't you just save the success result to a variable that you can update in the state to display on your Widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value returned by `makePostEditRequest(...)` when its future is resolved. This is done with `await` inside `async` block. For usage example see how  elsewhere in your code variable `response` receives the value from `http.post(...)` call when its future is resolved.